# Count different colors in a pixelated picture

Tags: color

I need the easiest way to be able to count the different colors in a pixelated picture that I have. So you understand what I'm talking about. If you look up counted cross stitch you'll see it comes with a pixelated picture on a graph. Each square is a different color. Well I need an app that I can upload my picture and it'll tell me how much I have for each color.  Is there anything like that

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. You can convert an image to indexed colour mode in software such as GIMP and Photoshop. Then you can count the number of colours used in the colour palette, but it won't tell you how much of each colour there is specifically.  Perhaps this is something you should ask about on a cross stitch forum. Googling "cross stitch software", I found [this list of cross stitch software](https://listoffreeware.com/free-cross-stitch-design-software-windows/) - I can't make any recommendations as I haven't tried any of them

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/130788/84899) to a similar question.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm already using a cross stitch program. Sadly it doesn't give me the total of each color. Ugh..back to counting..lol